# Accessing gdb console in Qt-Creator

Tags: gdb, qt-creator

Is there an access to the gdb console from Qt-Creator? For examining frames, dumping to file, etc. Seems a trivial feature but I couldn't find a clear reference to weather it exists or not.

I am using Qt-Creator 2.0.1 under Ubuntu 9.10

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`Window` > `Views` > `Debugger Log`. You can type commands in the left pane and send a line to gdb using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>. More info here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.2/creator-debug-mode.html#directly-interacting-with-native-debuggers

For examining frames using the "normal" views, especially the `Watchers` part of the Locals and Watchers view should probably be the better approach.

Comment: There is no `Views` menu under `Debug` menu - Any ides?

Comment: Ok, I found it under Window->Views.

Comment: The command line is superior in case I want to discuss what I see somebody via e-mail. Sending screenshots of the UI gets inconvenient quickly.

Comment: it's extremely inconvenient though if compare it against Xcode's lldb prompt

Comment: Now moved to View > Views > Debugger log.

Answer (score 0):

In the current Qt Creator 3.0.0 I found it after switching to the `Debugger` pane under `Window`→`Views`→`Debugger Log`. [Pictures.](https://github.com/AndreiCherniaev/QCoreApplication_quit_example)

The results display in the machine readable format, which is a bit messy to look at, but still fine since I use this only infrequently.

```
<53p vsink
>&"p vsink\n"
>~"$3 = {pCppObject_ = 0x0}"
>~"\n"
>53^done
```